# Example of a module such that every proper submodule is finitely generated but the module is not.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring with 1 and $M$ an $R$-module. What is an example such that $M$ is infinitely generated but every proper submodule is finitely generated.

Comment: Do you mean you want the module *not* to be finitely generated?

Comment: i want a module such that is not finitely generated but every proper submodule is fintely generated.

Answer (score 3):

The direct limit of $\Bbb Z$-modules:
$$\Bbb Z/p\to \Bbb Z/p^2\to \Bbb Z/p^3\to\cdots$$
is not finitely generated as a $\Bbb Z$ module but every proper submodule is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/p^k$ for some $k$.

**Edit**: For more information, please see [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prufer_group).

Comment: aren't there simpler examples.

Comment: Quang Hoang's notation is not standard, usually $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ denotes the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the prime $(p)$, which what he wrote certainly is not. But, another way to phrase $\varinjlim \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ which may be more amenable to your palette is as $\left\{e^{\frac{\pi i}{p^k}}:k\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$--i.e. all $p^\text{th}$-power roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Thanks, I'll edit it.